# Calculate inverse Function in Java

Tags: java, lambda

I have some function in Java.

```
Function<BigDecimal, BigDecimal> f = x -> {/*..*/}
```

Can I find input value by output, i.e. can I somehow calculate inverse function?

Thanks.

Comment: Not automatically of course.

Comment: In general case, inverse function can return *many values*, e.g. for `x -> x * x` the inverse values for `9` are `3` and `-3`; for `x -> sin(x)` the inverse values for `0` are `PI * k` (where k is *any integer number*); so you have to specify the domain (`[0..Inf)` in the first case and `[-PI/2..PI/2]` in the second) where inverse value should be looking for

Comment: no. if it is one-way function - you cannot. Your question is function specific...but you do not provide any specific function.

Comment: @Plirkee: *one-way function* means that its inverse function is just *very complex*, but technically it can well be computed

Comment: @Dmitry Bychenko: what’s the inverse function of `x -> 0`?

Comment: @Holger: for this *degenerated* function the domain could be just `{0}`: we answer `0` if we're asked to inverse `0` input or *no solution* if we're asked to inverse any other value

Comment: @Dmitry Bychenko: the domain of this question’s function is every possible `BigDecimal` value.

Comment: @Holger: you're quite right the domain of the direct function (`x -> 0`) is all integer values, the domain of the inverse function is just `{0}`; the inverse function, however, can return many values (all integer values on the `0` input) so in oreder to inverse function to be single value one, we have to define the domain of the values returned by the inverse function. I've suggested `{0}` (technically, any other single integer element set like '{123}' will do)

Answer (score 4):

You can calculate an inverse function only if your base function is an [injective function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Injective_function).

> In mathematics, an injective function or injection or **one-to-one function** is a function that **preserves distinctness**: it never maps distinct elements of its domain to the same element of its codomain.

Generally a java function is not injective. For example `toUpperCase` is not injective because

```
Ciao -> CIAO
ciao -> CIAO
cIaO -> CIAO
```

A function additionally can use internal information that depends on the time or is generated randomically. In these situations is not possible to create the inverse function.

For an **injective function however it is possible to create the inverse function**, but it is **not an automatic process**.

Comment: "it is not an automatic process". Do you mean it would be imposible to do it automatically? Why? Thanks

Comment: @pabvid is not an automatic process because you need to know the rules behind the one to one function. There is no automatic, mechanic process that can be used to find the original value, unless you apply the inverse logic in another function. You can apply the inverse logic only if you manually write it.

Answer (score 2):

There is no automatic "find the inverse" method in Java. However, you are of course free to implement the inverse function yourself. For many real-world functions their inverses are well documented and/or easily calculated with the right algorithm.

Answer (score -1):

```
public class myReverse {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int num=54321,reverse=0; //This 54321 is any input.you can Scan new number if you want.
        while(num !=0){
            int a=num%10;
            reverse=reverse*10 + a;
            num=num/10;
        }
        System.out.println(reverse);
    }
}
```